# Looping through a JSON local file

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to loop through this JSON file and get each event on my index instead of doing event[1].title, event[2].title etc. But I cannot figure out how, I did try a loop but it's not working.

```
[
  {
    "title": "eCommerce",
    "date": "12.03.2021",
    "time": "4:00 PM",
    "webinar": {
      "title": "Commerce",
      "link": "https://google.com"
    },
    "event": {
      "location": "Bucharest",
      "adress": "Piata Unirii 1"
    },
    "theme": "Disney Princess"
  },
  {
    "title": "Javascript Presentation",
    "date": "14.03.2021",
    "time": "12:00 PM",
    "event": { 
      "location": "Bucharest",
      "adress": "Remote"
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "Personal development webinar",
    "date": "21.04.2021",
    "time": "8:00 AM",
    "webinar": {
      "title": "Personal development webinar",
      "link": "https://meet.google.com"
    }
    },
    {
      "title": "Birthday Party",
      "date": "4.11.2021",
      "time": "7:00 PM",
      "event": {
        "location": "Cluj",
        "adress": "Centrul Vechi 21"
      },
      "theme": " '70s "
    }
]
```

P.S: This JSON data is passed with a XHR request into the index.

Comment: Show what you tried. You can use `event.forEach()` to loop over all the events in the array.

Comment: ok i got it but now i cannot acces the sub element like event.webinar.title, it shows it's undefined

Comment: It should be `event[i].webinar.title`

Comment: Or if you're using `forEach`, `iterationVariable.webinar.title`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
yourJsonObject.forEach(element => {
  // here you can access current title using element.title
})
```